# No way to change background color in Pixi.js v7

Tags: pixi.js

It's straightforward to set the background during initialization:
`const app = new PIXI.Application({ backgroundColor: 0x000000 })`

But it's seems impossible to change the background dynamically once it iss set during initialization.

I cannot fathom how something as simple as changing the background has become so tricky in the latest version of pixi.

In past versions, I could simply do something like this:
`app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0x000000`

But it no longer works in v7. The docs says backgroundColor method on renderer has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using TypeScript. Solved it by casting the `renderer` to `any`:

```
app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xff0000; // Throws error
(app.renderer as any).backgroundColor = 0xff0000; // Works
```

Not the cleanest solution, but made it work.

Answer (score 2):

In Pixi v7, it's now:

```js
app.renderer.background.color
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (now). Note that `app.renderer.background.alpha` can be used for the alpha channel.